# access facebook with ICS-SSL

Tags: facebook, delphi, https

I'm trying to access/login to Facebook with a program (OverbyteIcsHttpTst.exe) compiled with Delphi using the component ThttpCli ([ICS-SSL](http://www.overbyte.be/eng/products/ics.html), which is the latest version that supports https).

The idea is that I want to to access Facebook just like an ordinary browser does.

For example, I tried to login by using "post" to send some data to Facebook with the following code:

```
https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1

POSTDATA=charset_test=%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2C%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2C%E6%B0%B4%2C%D0%94%2C%D0%84&locale=en_US&email=yourmail%40yahoo.com&pass=yourpassword&charset_test=%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2C%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2C%E6%B0%B4%2C%D0%94%2C%D0%84&lsd=XAN99

CooKies : datr=1281135108-ea5c44949be49439183341b84db24aeb6c589ca1d31dc0c0da28d; expires=Sun, 05-Aug-2012 22:51:48 GMT; path=/; domain=.facebook.com;lsd=0ygNR; path=/; domain=.facebook.com;reg_fb_gate=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F; path=/; domain=.facebook.com;reg_fb_ref=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F; path=/; domain=.facebook.com
```

But I'm still stuck on the main page.  Is anything missing?

Thanks.

Comment: You may post it at the ICS forum which is very reactive.

Answer (score 0):

see if this helps you at all

https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=33184